# Product page (detail page) and parent category page is not showing after enabling the Use Flat Catalog Category from admin

Tags: ce-1.6.2.0

I have developed a magento store and using indexing feature to speed up the store front but when enable `Use Flat Catalog Category` the product detail page is not showing and parent category pages are not showing, this is not logging anything in log file nor it generate any php error i have enabled log from admin and magento developer mode is enable, php errors are on but nothing is coming up.

Just showing the message 
`No data received try reload the page`

Answer (score -1):

Try to run compilation at a time.

if it not helpfull, reindex with SSH.